# Error during debugging a Shell Script with SQL statement to V_$UNDOSTAT

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, shell

I want to store statistics on UNDO tablespace in one table every 6 hours.
I've created simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE SYS.TB_UNDOSTAT (
 MAX_UNDOBLKS NUMBER,
 MAX_QUERY_LENGTH NUMBER,
 MAX_QUERY_ID VARCHAR2(13),
 DATE_OF_STAT DATE,
 DMY_OF_STAT VARCHAR2(30),
 TIME_OF_STAT VARCHAR2(30));
```

After that I've created Oracle External Job:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
        (job_name=>'ACCUMULATE_UNDOSTAT',
        repeat_interval =>'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=05,11,17,23',
        job_type=>'EXECUTABLE',
        job_action=>'/home/oracle/scripts/UNDOSTAT/accumulate_undostat_111.bsh',
        enabled =>TRUE,
        auto_drop=>FALSE,
        comments=>'Take accumulate statistics from V$UNDOSTAT to 
        SYS.TB_UNDOSTAT one time through 6 hours On 111 Server'
        );
END;
```

Content of the accumulate_undostat_111.bsh file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
export ORACLE_SID=parustest
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH 
sqlplus -s << EOF
/ as sysdba
INSERT INTO FGA_OWNER.TB_UNDOSTAT (MAX_UNDOBLKS, MAX_QUERY_LENGTH,
MAX_QUERY_ID, DATE_OF_STAT, DMY_OF_STAT, TIME_OF_STAT)
SELECT max(undoblks), max(maxquerylen), maxqueryid, sysdate, to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY'), 
to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS') FROM SYS.V_$UNDOSTAT GROUP BY maxqueryid;
COMMIT;
exit;
EOF
exit 0
```

Job created without any problems. All necessary permissions have been granted.
But when I debug my shell script I have some problems:

```
[oracle@parustest111 UNDOSTAT]$ bash -o xtrace accumulate_undostat_111.bsh            + export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
+ ORACLE_HOME=/u01/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
+ export ORACLE_SID=parustest
+ ORACLE_SID=parustest
+ export PATH=/u01/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/oracle/bin
+ PATH=/u01/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/oracle/bin
+ sqlplus -s
to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS') FROM V_ GROUP BY maxqueryid
                                   *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
+ exit 0
[oracle@parustest111 UNDOSTAT]$
```

Can someone explain and help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in unix shell, `$` is the start of a variable, so your statement

```
FROM SYS.V_$UNDOSTAT
```

is interpreted by shell so that `$UNDOSTAT` looks for a unix variable called `UNDOSTAT`. To prevent this, you have to escape the statment

```
FROM SYS.V_\$UNDOSTAT
```

eg:

```
$ cat foo.bash
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus /<<EOF
select count(*) from v$session;
EOF

$ ./foo.bash

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jan 28 12:56:43 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select count(*) from v
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

vs:

```
$ cat foo2.bash
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus /<<EOF
select count(*) from v\$session;
EOF

$ ./foo2.bash

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jan 28 12:56:49 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
  COUNT(*)
----------
       184
```

better still though, if i were you, i'd have the SQL file seperate and just call it

```
sqlplus -s << EOF
/ as sysdba
@yoursql.sql
COMMIT;
exit;
EOF
```

where the `yoursql.sql` file just had all your `SQL`. no need to worry about escaping stuff then.